# Pandas to SQL conversion on Snowflake

Tags: sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to translate some pandas code to SQL. I have had success with the first snippet below.

```
days = 365

df['aux_sum'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['movement_qty'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(days,days).sum())
```

This translates to:

```
select SUM(movement_qty) OVER (
 partition by ID ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 364 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
 ) aux_sum
```

However, I haven't managed to get the second one below working:

```
df['aux_count'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['movement_qty'].transform(lambda x: (x>0).rolling(days,days).sum())
```

I am still not sure how to include the x>0 condition into the query. Any thoughts on what this should be? Thanks!

Comment: Definitely test this thoroughly, but how about `SELECT COUNT(movement_qty)` instead of `SELECT SUM(movement_qty)`, with the rest of the query the same?

Comment: Thanks Peter!

I have tested this - doesn't work because there are some rows where the movement_qty is 0 and I need the count for when movement_qty > 0.

Comment: Ah of course, I should have realized that. Maybe `SELECT COUNT_IF(movement_qty > 0)`? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html

Comment: Perfect!!! This works - thanks a ton, Peter!!

Comment: That's great to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter mentioned in the comment above, the following query does the trick for me:

```
select COUNT_IF(movement_qty>0) OVER (
 partition by ID ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 364 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
 ) aux_count
```

Adding this in here in case it helps anyone and since I can't mark Peter's comment as an answer.